# Cross referencing JSON and MySQL?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, json, discord.js

I have written a "buy" feature for a discord bot which inserts the `id` of the item into the corresponding table in mysql.

Example buy:

```
const join = args.join(" ")
let item = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('commands/economy/resources/items.json', "utf8"));


//Horses
const Horse1 = item.Horse1


        //Buy Horse1
        if (join === Horse1.name) {

            let itemName = Horse1.name
            let itemLuck = Horse1.luck
            let itemId = Horse1.ID.toString()
            let itemPrice = Horse1.price.toString()

            //Account Check
            if (rows.length < 1) { return message.channel.send("You do not have an account with The Iron Bank. Use ``;start`` to open one.") };
            //Item Check
            if (rows[0].horse === itemId) { return message.channel.send(`❌ | You already have a ${itemName}!`) }
            //Money Check
            if (rows[0].bank < itemPrice) { return message.channel.send(`You do not have enough coins in your account to buy **${itemName}**. It costs ${itemPrice} coins. You have ${rows[0].bank} coins`) };


            //DB Update
            con.query(`UPDATE economy SET horse = '${itemId}', horseluck = '${itemLuck}', bank = bank-${itemPrice} WHERE user = ${message.author.id}`)

            //Bought
            message.channel.send(`✅ | Purchased ${itemName} for ${itemPrice} coins.`)
        };
```

Long story short, I need to pull the `name:` from an `id:` and cross reference it with `rows[0].horse` / `rows[0].weapon`

Here is the code inside my mySQL select query:

```
  //Direct to start if not in DB
    if (rows.length < 1) {

        return message.channel.send("You do not have an account with The Iron Bank. Use ``;start`` to open one.")

    };

    let horse = rows[0].horse;
    let weapon = rows[0].weapon;
    let armour = rows[0].armour;
    let luck = (rows[0].horseluck + rows[0].weaponluck + rows[0].armourluck)
    console.log()

    return message.channel.send(`**Horse**: ${horse}\n**Weapon**: ${weapon ? weapon : "None"}\n**Armour**: ${armour ? armour : "None"}\n**Luck Bonus**: ${luck ? "+"+luck+"%" : "None"}`);
```

But the above prints out the ID of the Horse instead of the name in `message.channel.send`. How would I cross reference the ID from the MySQL to the ID in the JSON and have the name print out in the `message.channnel.send`instead?

```js
Example of my JSON file:

    {
"Horse1":{
        "ID": 1,
        "name": "Dornish Sand Steed",
        "description": "Splendid beasts",
        "type": "Horses",
        "price": "100000",
        "luck": "5.0"
    },
 "Horse2":{
        "ID": 2,
        "name": "Arabian",
        "description": "Preferred war mounts",
        "type": "Horses",
        "price": "50000",
        "luck": "2.0"
    },
"Weapon1":{
        "ID": 1,
        "name": "Longclaw",
        "description": "Valyrian steel sword that was the ancestral weapon of House Mormont",
        "type": "Weapons",
        "price": "100000",
        "luck": "5.0"
    },
"Weapon2":{
        "ID": 2,
        "name": "Oathkeeper",
        "description": "Valyrian steel sword made from House Starks greatsword",
        "type": "Weapons",
        "price": "50000",
        "luck": "2.0"
    },
}
```

(I am aware that the SQL queries in this code are prone to SQL injection. This is just for testing before I get round to using mysql.format)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve this:

Converted the JSON object values into an array using `Object.values(item)` then used the ID to index the array after converting the rows[0] value into an INT as per the below. If the value is undefined (null in this case because it can't have any other value than the ID's specified in the JSON) see as "None".

```
    let horse = rows[0].horse;
    let weapon = rows[0].weapon;
    let armour = rows[0].armour;
    let luck = (rows[0].horseluck + rows[0].weaponluck + rows[0].armourluck)

    function getItemName(id){
        return (id == undefined)? "None" : Object.values(item)[id - 1].name;
    }

    let horseName = getItemName(parseInt(horse))
    let weaponName = getItemName(parseInt(weapon) + 5)
    let armourName = getItemName(parseInt(armour) + 10)

    //5 items of each type


    return message.channel.send(`**Horse**: ${horseName}\n**Weapon**: ${weaponName}\n**Armour**: ${armourName}\n**Luck Bonus**: ${luck ? "+"+luck+"%" : "None"}`);
```

Comment: I changed the ID's for each item to have different ID's as well as the field types in mySQL to ``int``. So in this case it would be: ```function getItemName(id) {return Object.values(items)[id -1].name}

        let horseName = (isNaN(horse) || horse == null)? "None" : getItemName(horse);
        let weaponName = (isNaN(weapon) || weapon == null)? "None" : getItemName(weapon);
        let armourName = (isNaN(armour) || armour == null)? "None" : getItemName(armour);```